# Accessing Media content of Android wear

Tags: android, wear-os, android-music-player

I'm developing an android wear music application which is to play offline music. Similar in normal android applications, I'm trying to access the internal storage of the watch and get the songs using ContentResolver. Here's the code I'm using:

```
        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query( android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null );
        if( cursor.moveToFirst() )
        {
            while(cursor.moveToNext())
            {
                int idColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex( android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID );
                int titleColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE );
                int artistColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST );
            }
        }
```

But the problem is, I 'm not getting any results for this query. I'm getting `false` for `cursor.moveToFirst()`.

Just to make sure I have offline music(stored in the device), I disconnected the watch from the phone and paired with a headset and tried playing, and it worked fine(I have 7 songs).

What is the issue I'm having here?

Comment: Is there anything in logcat when you make these calls? For example, a permission failure may appear there.

Comment: @String, no I don't get any error in logcat.

Comment: Then this is beyond me, sorry. I suspect that Google Play Music on Wear stores its media in a non-standard location (based on some results I've seen elsewhere); that may be the source of this problem, but I can't suggest a solution, I'm afraid.

Comment: Yeah, that seems the only logical explanation. Thanks anyway ;)